# My application is stopping

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to make the button redirect to another class, my application is stopping when I try to click the button Play and this is what the logcat says

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.kenneth.rusa.Play.onCreate(Play.java:26)
```

Play, java:26 is

```
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playb);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Play.this, GamePanelEasy.class));
}
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".Play">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I don't have any errors but it's still crashing, I don't know why the logcat says I have error in line 26 which is  `play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){  }`

Thanks for the help guys I found out what's my problem playb was been duplicated from another class I changed it to easyb so it works fine now thanks!

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what does it change?

Comment: I don't know which is line 26, but I would assume your play button variable is null for some reason.

Comment: are you sure ? you declare GamePanelEasy in manifest ?

Comment: @RichardGoodman yes yes

Comment: @Saveen Yes I did.

Comment: @KennethAbuel if you are sure that Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playb); referencing to correct id that is inside the same layout of this activity then try clean and building the project or changing the id..

Comment: @KennethAbuel May be have duplicate id's with same name or you are taking reference of wrong id in *code*.

Comment: @kennethabuel what is your code in 26 line number

Answer (score 0):

If your app crashes in between lines you posted there is only one possibility. You are trying to invoke `setOnClickListener()` method to a `null reference` here:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Check if `R.id.playb` id is in layout you inflate in `onCreate()`.

Comment: How do I check if R.id.playb ID is in layout?

Comment: Open your layout file, find a button you want to attach onClickListener to and check if its `id` is set to `R.id.playb`. Should look like this: `android:id="@+id/R.id.playb"`

Comment: Oh, I found out why it's crashing there's a duplicate R.id.play, I didn't notice it but I found it out now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name="GamePanelEasy"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

--have you declare your second activity in the manifest?